# Why does asp net core Identity hit the database when clicking on the account/manage links?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a bare asp net core web application with authentication set up (individual).

After successfully logging in, and clicking on the email (top right corner), this takes me to `Identity/Account/Manage`.

[image: Screenshot of account management]

Whilst clicking the different tabs (i.e. Email or Password), I noticed that a new call is requested for the database.

Below is an example screenshot of the log.

[image: Screenshot of log]

Why does it keep hitting the database after changing the link? It does not do this when I request a page which has the `[Authorize]` Attribute on?

Comment: Did you look at the code that executes when you hit that endpoint? What does it do? You have the code in front of you, so this is probably something you could learn more quickly and thoroughly by looking.

Comment: I dont have it in front of me as I have not scaffolded the default Identity UI

Comment: You're running the app, but don't have the source code for the app in front of you?

Comment: Tell me something, have you ever used asp net core identity UI? (I think I know the answer to this question).

Comment: I have not used the scaffolded UI, but I have used ASP.NET Core Identity. That's really irrelevant to the fact that you've got everything you need to research this. You can look at the code on your machine that the template provided. It's also open source, so [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5/Account/Manage) was just a quick web search away.

Comment: After looking at the source I linked to, is that enough to answer your question? It needs to look up details in the database so that the UI knows what to display, and in some cases which page to redirect you to. For example, the Password page needs to know whether you have a password already set, so it queries the DB. If you do have a password already set, then you are presented with a UI to change your password. If you don't have a password already set, it redirects you to a page where you may set an initial password. Don't be afraid to crack things open and take a look for yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will have to look into this in more detail, as I mentioned in my question that when my own method is decorated with an [Authorize] attribute, it doesnt need to query. So I will try investigate when it does need to query and when it doesnt.

Comment: The Authorize method just makes sure you're authenticated. Assuming you've used the default templates and are already logged in, the system doesn't have to hit the DB again to check that you're authenticated. It can see the authentication ticket in the cookie that was issued to you and is sent with subsequent requests.